# Index data for searching

Tags: .net, indexing

Basically, I have a large set of data (a collection of models with ID, name, description, etc..) that I want to index and then search. I have a good understanding of how indexing works, but I haven't been able to find any good resources on how to go about implementing it in .NET. Apologies for any incorrect terminology, and feel free to correct me if I am thinking about this the wrong way. I've looked into lucene.net, but I'm not sure if it's the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: @usr ideally cluster, but I'm open to different suggestions

Comment: I think usr was looking for a little more detail on what you want to index.  The size, shape and nature of the data makes a huge difference.

Comment: Full text search? Clustering documents? More details required!

Comment: Sorry about that! The data is a large collection of models that my project uses. Each one has an ID, name, description, etc.. I'm hoping to be able to quickly and accurately search through this data. Thanks for your patience with me!